# Using Python script to create map from external source via ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, wms, geoprocessing-service

Is it possible in ArcGIS Server to write a python script to pull features from a third party database in real-time?

Essentially I want to create a service where I can pass in filter parameters (BBOX, along with field queries ( ie...where car = 'Honda') via a service.

My python script would query my external database and create features/(Possibly a heat map) and return an image (wms) to the user.

I will have lots of data (in low millions) so I want to generate an image/heat map on server side and return to user.

Is this what a geoprocessing script would be?

The database is highly optimized and I can pull 2 million records in a second so I'd like to be able to have real time images generated (ie...as user pans and scrolls, my python script runs and pulls new data/image)

Essentially I want to have a custom "data store" utilizing python where I can serve out WMS?

Comment: This does not sound like a use case for a Geoprocessing Service to me.  I think you should review these Q&As (http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcgis-server%5D+heatmap) and consider revising your question to try and attract potential answerers to start commenting, and hopefully answering.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use ArcPy and Python to write a Python script tool which can be published as a Geoprocessing Service to ArcGIS for Server.

That Python script might be able to pull features from a third party database in real-time but the code to do that would need to use non-GIS libraries.